# Статистика времени работы

Tags: python, windows

Aida, в числе прочего, так же предоставляет информацию о:

- Время первой загрузки
- Время первого завершения
- Общее время работы
- Общее время простоя
- Самое длительное время работы
- Самое длительное время простоя
- Количество перезагрузок

Как получить эту информацию средствами python? 
Буду признателен за помощь с любым из пунктов

Comment: Гугли то же самое, но с приставкой `wmi`.